# How to fix error after Hibernate upgrade in Java application

Tags: java, hibernate

## Issue

we have recently upgraded the hibernate version to 5.4.0 final
after that we noticed that  all named queries started failing

tried to find the root cause and found that its only failing for list and if we try it to change it to streams, its working fine.

sample query :
List employees= new ArrayList();
        employees.addAll((List) getCurrentSession().getNamedQuery("getEmployeeById").setParameterList("Ids", ids).list());

## Stack Trace

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.classic.NamedParameterInformationImpl cannot be cast to java.util.ArrayList
org.hibernate.hql.internal.classic.QueryTranslatorImpl.getNamedParameterLocs(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:639)
org.hibernate.loader.Loader.buildNamedParameterLocMap(Loader.java:1090)
org.hibernate.loader.Loader.createSubselects(Loader.java:1053)
org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:1018)
org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:948) 
org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:340)
org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2695) 
org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2678) 
org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2512)
org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2507)
org.hibernate.hql.internal.classic.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:1038)
org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:224)
org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1511)
org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.doList(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1561)
org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1529)
```

Comment: Did you try checking if you are able to return list from query?
like query.getResultList();

Comment: yes tried it  ,it gives the same error for all list operations

Comment: Maybe you should provide some examples of the code that triggers the error?

Comment: sample query :   
List<Employees> employees= new ArrayList<Employee>();
        employees.addAll((List<Employee>) getCurrentSession().getNamedQuery("getEmployeeById").setParameterList("Ids", ids).list());